# Want to show value of variable in alert box

Tags: c#, .net

I want to show the value of the variable in Alert box so please give me suggestion for that. Here is my code.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
        int sum3; 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            { 
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable("mainTable");
                 DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("Name");
                dTable.Columns.Add(Name);
                 DataColumn Marks = new DataColumn("Marks");
                dTable.Columns.Add(Marks); 
                DataColumn Marks2 = new DataColumn("Marks2");
                dTable.Columns.Add(Marks2); 
                DataColumn Total = new DataColumn("Total");
                dTable.Columns.Add(Total); 
                int sum = 0;
                int sum2 = 0; 
                DataRow dRow = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    dRow = dTable.NewRow();
                    dRow["Name"] = i + " - Sagar";
                    dRow["Marks"] = i;
                    sum += i;
                    dRow["Marks2"] = i + 5;
                    sum2 += i + 5;
                    dRow["Total"] = i + i + 5;
                    sum3 += i + i + 5;
                    dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
                }
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "showAlert(" + sum3.ToString() + ");", true);

                       aspDataGrid.DataSource = dTable;
                aspDataGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            marks1.Text = "Total Marks : " + sum3.ToString();
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "showAlert(" + sum3.ToString() + ");", true);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try This Using Session Like...

In Your Page_Load Event write
Session["sum3"]=sum3 After For Loop And Then You Can write This Code in
Button Submit Button
 
 

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "showAlert(" + Session["sum3"] + ");", true);`

Answer (score 1):

The correct line is:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert(" + sum3.ToString() + ");", true);
```

Replace it in btn_Submit_Click and Page_Load. It will work!

Comment: You just copied the same line from my code... please don't do like that.... and i have already got the answer from Manoj Savalia

Comment: Don't you see they're not the same? The difference is in 'alert(' instead of 'showAlert('. Please pay attention. And it works. Also my answer differs from Manoj Savalia's answer, so there's no contradictions.